# How can I find out if the mouse is hovering/clicking on a pygame sprite (not shaped as a rectangle or circle)

Tags: python, pygame

So I am making this button and I need to find out two things

**1 - When is the user hovering over it?**

***2 - When is the user clicking on it?***

As you can see these [buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWD4Q.png) are oddly shaped

[image: Example Button]

I have tried looking on the **pygame forums** but those only state how to find out if two sprites are colliding.

Answer (score 2):

Just handle the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event, and check the `event.pos` against the `rect` of each of your sprites.  If there's a collision, that's the one that was clicked on.

It's the same for hovering, except you need to grab the mouse position each frame via the `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` function.

If you put all your button sprites into a `SpriteGroup`, it will be easy to do these checks.

For oddly shaped sprites, it may help to use a Sprite mask.  This is an extra-check made (after the rectangle collision shows true) at the per-pixel level.  So while the mouse may have done some action within the bounds of the Sprite's rectangle, maybe it was not truly over the visible part of the Sprite's image.

Luckily the PyGame Sprite library makes the creation of a mask easy, and if defined, it will automatically be used as part of the collision detection.

```
class MaskedSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, image, x, y ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = image.convert_alpha()
        self.mask        = pygame.mask.from_surface( self.image )  # <<-- HERE
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
```

There are a few simple rules around mask creation.  If the image has a transparent background, that will be used to determine what is part/not-part of the sprite-collision.

Otherwise there needs to be a difference in colour between the background/foreground of 127 colour units (the default). This can be changed with the `threshold` parameter to `pygame.mask.from_surface()`.

There is also the `pygame.mask.from_threshold()` function.

To be honest, just use a transparent background, and everything will be OK.

*Everything.*